# .R files not opening suddenly on anaconda

Tags: r, anaconda

I use Anaconda for both python and R, I updated today, after that none of my R files are opening. I wrote a block of code, saved and tried to open, but after it opens, the entire file is empty. 
I tried uninstalling and installing again, but its the same. Can anyone help me out with this please, my college project work is struck in between and I see all my developed codes gone suddenly.

Thank You in Advance

Comment: Did you try to open them in a text editor?  They are just text files.

Answer (score 0):

I’ve had this happen to me a few times. My work around is the navigate to the file in file explorer, right click on it, and open in a text editor. This should provide you your code. From there copy and paste back into your IDE. Further, saving the file with UTF-8 encoding supposedly helps as well, but I have yet to determine if this is a full workaround.